# Picking in true 3D isometric view

Tags: math, view, 3d, 2d, isometric

To view my 3D environment, I use the "true" 3D isometric projection (flat square on XZ plane, Y is "always" 0). I used the explanation on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection to come to how to do this transformation:
The projection matrix is an orthographic projection matrix between some minimum and maximum coordinate.
The view matrix is two rotations: one around the Y-axis (n * 45 degrees) and one around the X-axis (arctan(sin(45 degrees))).
The result looks ok, so I think I have done it correctly.

But now I want to be able to pick a coordinate with the mouse. I have successfully implemented this by rendering coordinates to an invisible framebuffer and then getting the pixel under the mouse cursor to get the coordinate. Although this works fine, I would really like to see a mathematical sollution because I will need it to calculate bounding boxes, frustums of the area on the screen and stuff like that.

My instincts tell me to:
- go from screen-coordinates to 2D projection coordinates (or how do you say this, I mean transforming screen coordinates to a coordinate between -1 and +1 for both axisses, with y inverted)
- untransform the coordinate with the inverse of the view-matrix.
- yeah... untransform this coordinate with the inverse of the projection matrix, but as my instincts tell, this won't work as everything will have the same Z-coordinate.

This, while every information is perfectly available on the isometric view (I know that the Y value is always 0). So I should be able to convert the isometric 2D x,y coordinate to a calculated 3d (x, 0, z) coordinate without using scans or something like that.

My math isn't bad, but this is something I can't seem to grasp.

Edit: IMO. every different (x, 0, z) coordinate corresponds to a different (x2, y2) coordinate in isometric view. So I should be able to simply calculate a way from (x2, y2) to (x, 0, z). But how?

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

there is something called `project` and `unproject` to transform screen to world and vice versa....

Comment: In my experience, this has never worked for me. And if I understand correctly, that's only useful for ray-picking. I don't need ray-picking here, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to miss some core concepts here (it’s been a while since I did this stuff, so minor errors included):

- There are 3 kinds of coordinates involved here (there are more, these are the relevant ones): Scene, Projection and Window

  - **Scene (3D)** are the coordinates in your world
  - **Projection (3D)** are those coordinates after being transformed by camera position and projection
  - **Window (2D)** are the coordinates in your window. They are generated from projection by scaling x and y appropriately and discarding z (z is still used for “who’s in front?” calculations)

You can **not** transform from *window* to *scene* with a matrix, as every point in *window* does correspond to a whole line in *scene*. If you want (x, 0, z) coordinates, you can generate this line and intersect it with the y-plane.

If you want to do this by hand, generate two points in *projection* with the same (x,y) and different (arbitrary) z coordinates and transform them to *scene* by multiplying with the inverse of your projection transformation. Now intersect the line through those two points with your y-plane and you’re done.

Note that there should be a “static” solution (a single formula) to this problem – if you solve this all on paper, you should get to it.

Comment: I wasn't missing the core concepts you wrote but I wasn't able to use the right terminology which probably made it very unclear to read, so thanks for that. If I understand you correctly, you are telling me to do ray-picking, but instead of searching for intersections with objects, I just need to find the intersection with Y=0?

Comment: Yes, that would achieve your goal. You could also solve a bunch of equations to get a `screen(a,b) -> scene(x, 0, z)` function. But unless speed is really important, using an existing solution would probably be easier (assuming coding is more your thing than math :).